What was the first brilliant move ever recorded?
What and when was the first brilliant move recorded in modern chess?
This would be based on Chess.com's newest definition of a brilliant move. Not just in chess.com games, in all games.
For reference, Chess.com's latest definition of a brilliant move:

...a Brilliant move is when you find a good piece sacrifice.


There are additional conditions:

You should not be in a bad position after a Brilliant move
You should not be completely winning even if you hadn't found the move.
We are also more generous in defining a piece sacrifice for newer players compared to those who are higher-rated.



Do you mean the original Chess.com definition or after they updated the definition (2nd version)?

I mean after they updated it. I'll edit the question.

What is chess.com's definition of a brilliant move?

Are you asking for someone to dig in Chess.com records to find the first games played after they published their new definition ?

@bof Chess.com's definition of a brilliant move can be found here:  Is there a way to get blunders, mistakes and inaccuracies using Stockfish?

Do you mean just games on chess.com, or all chess?

How far back are we allowed to go?  Was it still "chess" before the en passant rule?  Before 0-0 and 0-0-0 got their current meaning?  All the way back to medieval chess with fers and alfil (in which case do they count as "pieces" even though an alfil is weaker than a pawn)?

I mean all chess, not just chess.com, and with the modern set of chess rules. I'll edit the question.

@NoamD.Elkies, do you say that an alfil is weaker than a pawn because it cannot promote? Can you clarify, please?

@paulgarrett Alfil cannot promote and only has access to 8 of the 64 squares.  Then again a pawn could only promote to a fers, and Wikipedia's Alfil article suggests that an alfil was still more valuable than a pawn.  Since the OP has now specified modern chess I suppose its moot whether an alfil sacrifice would count as "brilliant".

The definition of a brilliant move (quoting from chess.com since that's the reference chosen) should be edited into the body of the question.

Now the "definition" has been added the question is, IMO, impossible to answer - the "definition" is just not well enough, err, defined. Presumably chess.com sticks it through an engine and applies some algorithm to the numbers that come out. What is that algorithm? Once you have that download some of Greco's games and see if anything comes out as a first stab.

Thanks for adding the link @SecretAgentMan
